# "Send email" action not working to send email to poster of comment

Tags: comments, emails, actions, rules

I have successfully set up email notifications on my client's blog for administrators when new comments are posted and am now trying to set it up to send a thank-you email to the poster of the comment as well. I set it up using triggers and actions as described [here](http://www.jasonhooker.com/index.php?q=configure-drupal-notification-on-new-comments).

I put in `[comment:author:mail]` in the "Recipient" field on the action configuration form as suggested in the note right below that field, but it seems that it never sends the email. I initially tested it using my own email address and it worked fine, then I posted a comment as an anonymous user using two different email addresses of mine but never received an email. Why is `[comment:author:mail]` not working? I'm using other variables in the body of the email (e.g. `[comment:node:title]`) and they're working fine.

I tried using Maillog as @tenken suggested below, which verified that the problem isn't with mail delivery but rather with the email not being populated correctly:

Here's a screenshot that shows the email to the administrator is working correctly, but not the thank-you email:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous user account doesn't have an email address to send to. You will want to use the value of the field that collects the email address instead of author:mail.

Comment: Thank you. How would I access that field? Since I didn't get a solution here after several days, I also posted this on StackOverflow where [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25321971/560114) pointed out the same thing you did; do you happen to know the answer to my follow-up question there?

Comment: Which is: "With regard to a custom field, there is already an email field that commenters see, so will I need to hide the default field in order to avoid having 2 email fields show up once I create the custom one?"

Comment: I didn't have to create a second email field for comments, but I did have to create one in the first place. That may be because anonymous users have permission to create comments on my site. (People -> Permissions -> Comments -> Post Comments)

Comment: And in my case, I can access that field in Rules with comment:field-email

Comment: I allowed anonymous commenters to leave an email by setting the "Anonymous commenting" setting for the "Blog" content type to "Anonymous posters may leave their contact information". So I'm guessing I should change that back to "Anonymous posters may not enter their contact information" and create a custom email field instead?

Comment: Ah in that case you may try comment:mail, instead of comment:author:mail

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick! Not sure why I didn't notice that in the list of available tokens. I was also able to use `comment:name` to say `Hi [name]` in the body of the email.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be very hard to answer -- email is tricky as PHP just hands off your email to the underlying/remote mail system. I suspect nobody can tell you exactly what's wrong without in-depth examination of your setup.

But, the [Mail Developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/maillog) module will allow you to "try" to send and log raw emails without actually sending them, you can likely look for differences between mails that do send -- and the emails you think are not sending correctly.

> Maillog provides an easy possibility to log all Mails for debugging
>   purposes. It's possible to prevent the mails to being sent, so there
>   is no need for an extra mail server to test the mail functionality of
>   other modules or the drupal core. Additionally you can immediately
>   display the mail through the devel dpm() facility.
>
> If you like to upgrade from a previous dev release, please disable,
>   uninstall and reinstall again. There's no upgrade procedure yet.

Also see the similar modules on the project page -- for additional tools to debug and resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this...but one of the email addresses I used was the same as the one I had successfully tested by hard-coding it into the email field, so I was thinking that the `[comment:author:mail]` variable wasn't working correctly...thanks for the suggestion in any case.

Comment: As I suspected, email delivery isn't the problem - see the screenshot I added to my question.